# Fixing Buggy JQuery Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, hover

I've been trying to create a smooth hover animation using JQuery. So the idea is that when you hover over the picture both the image and the text increase in size.

However the image is kind of buggy when you hover over it and the text scrolls as you can see in the jsfiddle included. Is there anything I can do to make it smoother without the text scrolling?

Comment: https://codepen.io/MotionCity/pen/Pbrxjr

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property overflow: hidden;
inside the css class .textBoxes, like this:

```
.textBoxes
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I added that however the text is still moving when you hover over the photo and the hover animation is still buggy